# How to customize the scrollbar in React Js?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm working in ReactJs and unable to find out how can I customize scroll for a specific section.

```
<div>
  <div>
      Some header
  </div> 
  <div style={{ height: "210px", overflow: "auto",   }}>
    // this section is only scrollable and I want to customize this scroll bar.                
  </div>
</div>
```

It was easy in html because I was able to use webkit. However, I don't know how to do this thing in react any help will be really appreciated. Thanks well in advance!

If I use the webkit then I'm getting this sort of error:
[image]

Comment: upload your css part also

Comment: If you include the same styles you would use in vanilla HTML does it not work?

Comment: Hey @DBS I don't know actually how to use webkit in reactjs.

Comment: When you say "use webkit", do you mean `-webkit-(propertyName)` styles? Because I can't think of any obvious reason you couldn't just use those like any other style in your `style={ {...} }` object (Though I guess the property names will need to be wrapped in quotes, but otherwise I would imagine it would be identical)

Comment: @DBS I added the error which I'm getting while using webkit.

Comment: Now, it works I just added the code in the external stylesheet and it works.

Comment: The `::-webkit-scrollbar` is the selector, and since inline CSS applies to the element it's attached to, a selector isn't included. But yes, as you have discovered, if you need to apply styles to pseudo-elements you will need to use an external stylesheet (As the element doesn't exist in the markup, so styles can't be added in-line)

Answer (score 1):

Styling scrollbars is somewhat possible, depending on the browser. if you want to completely restyle it, you will have to hide the real scrollbar, create a new one, and add functionality to it with code.

It is probably easier to use a tool like simplebar, which works with react:

```js
import SimpleBar from 'simplebar-react';
import 'simplebar/dist/simplebar.min.css';

const App = () => (
<div>
  <div>
      Some header
  </div> 
  <SimpleBar style={{ maxHeight: 210}}>
        // this section is only scrollable and I want to customize this scroll bar.                
  </SimpleBar>
</div>
);
```

https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/tree/master/packages/simplebar-react

Answer (score -1):

Use this package [react-custom-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-scrollbars) for custom behaviour and styling.

Also it is compatible with all browsers(Chrome/Firefox/Safari) etc.